# LSTM input data in PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I would like to use deep learning to implement a regression using LSTM, the problem which I faced was **how to define an input and output layer**. My dataset has 5 features which have been recorded in different spatial points in 1000 time step. As I realized I must reshape my dataset to a 3D ndarray of (samples, Timestep, Features) and I have not understood yet, how to reshape it. The code below is my not successful effort to achieve the goal.

```
# Loading libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
from pandas import read_csv
from matplotlib import pyplot
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from keras.layers import InputLayer
```

### Loading data

```
df = pd.read_excel("concate35w270.xlsx")
df = df.astype('float32')
```

### Showing Data

```
T|x|y|f1|f2|f3|f4|f5
1|0|0|15.0|0.10|0.010|+0.02|0.1|
1|1|1|14.1|0.11|0.012|-0.02|0.2|
1|2|2|14.9|0.12|0.011|+0.01|0.2|
2|0|0|15.0|0.11|0.012|+0.02|0.1|
2|1|1|15.1|0.12|0.013|-0.03|0.1|
2|2|2|14.9|0.13|0.014|+0.04|0.3|
...
```

f is my feature and in each time step and x,y I have values for my features.

### locating data and reshaping

```
y = df.iloc[:,5]
X1 = df.iloc[:,0]
X2 = df.iloc[:,1]
X3 = df.iloc[:,2]
X4 = df.iloc[:,3]
X5 = df.iloc[:,4]
X = np.column_stack((X1,X2,X3,X4,X5))
x = np.reshape(1000,1,5)
y = np.reshape(1000,1,1)
```

All efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: If you add a bit of sample data, it will be easier to test. A quick google outputted this though, might be helpful: https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/

Comment: @prp ok. I will edit my question with samples of data to become more clear.

Comment: @prp I have put more info in my question so if you can check it out. Thanks

Comment: hmm.. 1000 is the second item in the reshape for sure, and the last is the number of samples. So by elimination, the first item should be 1?
Also, your sample data is quite weird since it does not seem to match the code snippet that follows.